# Entity types cannot be generic

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, exception

I am using the following function in the Domain Service,

```
public IQueryable<Dictionary<discussion_category, List<discussion_board>>> GetDiscussion_categoriesWithBoards()
{
    return new[] {
        GetDiscussion_categories().Select(c => new {
            Category = c,
            Boards = GetDiscussion_boardsByCategory(c.ID).ToList()
        }).ToDictionary(i => i.Category, i => i.Boards.ToList())
    }.AsQueryable();
}
```

seems to have no errors and i get the following error while compiling,

> Type 'Dictionary`2' is not a valid
>   entity type.  Entity types cannot be
>   generic.

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `Dictionary<discussion_category, List<discussion_board>>` is not a valid type to send over Ria services, unfortunately you can only send `IQueryable<Entity>` (As far as I can remember)

If you want to send something else, you might want to have a look at the [InvokeOperation](http://mwoodhall.wordpress.com/2009/12/17/ria-services-examples-using-invokeoperation/) and creating Complex Types (see Complex types in this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/digital_ruminations/archive/2010/10/28/complextypes-in-ria-services.aspx)).